# InstanceOf some type from runtime, Scala

Tags: scala, reflection, types, runtime

The idea, is that, for example we got type of some object:

```
val tm = getTypeTag("String here").tpe
//> tm: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = java.lang.String

// for example I got another val or var, of some type:

val tmA: Any = "String here"
//> tmA: Any = String here
```

How to make `tmA.InstanceOf(tm)` (it is a mnemonic code)? 'Cause `tm` it is not a type alias, and we cant make `InstanceOf[tm]` exactly.

**EDITED**

there I mean analog function for `asIstanceOf`, to make a sort of type casting

**EDITED2**

I'll partly answer my question myself. So if we have `TypeTags` is is all easy!

```
def tGet[T](t: TypeTag[T], obj: Any): T = obj.asInstanceOf[T]
```

It is a harder situation if we only got `Type` and not the whole `TypeTag[T]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [mirror](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Mirrors) to reflect the instance:

```
val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

def isTm(a: Any) = mirror.reflect(a).symbol == tm.typeSymbol
```

And then:

```
scala> isTm("String here": Any)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> isTm(List("String here"): Any)
res1: Boolean = false
```

I don't think I have to tell you what a bad idea this is, though.

Comment: thx for reply! that's right, and is not a good idea. but the idea, is that I have 100% sure, that the object is of that type. Mb I have a sort of mistake in my question, but I meant `.asInstanceOf(tm)` so to make a sort of casting..

so for example `tm` is `ru.Type = String`, and function `myAsInstanceOf(tm)` is in fact the same as `asInstanceOf[String]`

Comment: Oh, I did misunderstand then—I read `InstanceOf` as meaning `isInstanceOf`. I think you'll need a type tag (or macro) for the cast—I'll try to put together an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: thx! that would be great... And I'll try to avoid this, and post here, if it would be possible of cource.

Answer (score -1):

You need just to use type attribute of your variable after the variable.
As an example you can write:

val h ="hello"
val b:Any = "hhhh"

val stringB: String = b.asInstanceOf[h.type]

println(stringB)

Comment: But he's trying to cast to the type _represented by_ a `Type` value (or a `TypeTag` value), not to the type _of_ some given value.